# I got the Taxonomist badge for a tag I didn't create?

Tags: support, tags, badges, meta

This morning, I received the Taxonomist badge for the [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits) tag on Meta.

I do not recall creating this tag; looking at it's history on both Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange, I don't seem to have had a hand in it's creation at all.

On Meta Stack Exchange, it is [created on Nov 30, 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/157193/revisions).

On Meta Stack Overflow, it was [created on April 18, 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250805/revisions). My questions using this tag on Meta Stack Overflow were all migrated to Meta Stack Exchange.

My earliest use of the tag is [July 24, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/close-vote-review-failed) - well after it was created on Meta Stack Overflow, and well before Meta Stack Exchange was created.

I figured that maybe I created a different tag that was made a tag synonym. But I don't see any synonyms in the tag wiki. My best guess is that maybe I created a tag that was merged into the "review-audits"? I can't find any merge requests though. A search for "[retag-request] review-audits" yields no result either on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bretag-request%5D%20review-audits) or on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bretag-request%5D%20review-audits).

So, it seems to me I got this badge in error. If that is the case, I would like the SE team to take it back. I don't need credit for something I haven't done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created the tag on April 17th by [editing a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/250143/revisions):

> Fixed grammar. Broke up long sentence, to make it easier to parse. Added tags.

Shog added a tag wiki the next day when he migrated posts over from Meta.SE. You confused the tag wiki edit with the tag creation date; tag wikis are created *separately* from the tag.

Comment: That explains it. I'm aware that the tag wiki is not the same as the tag; but you can't have a tag wiki before there is a tag. So the tag still pre-dated my first question. I should have remembered to check my edit history as well.