# Why was I awarded the taxonomist badge?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, badges

This happened more than 3 years ago but I just noticed today, I don't look at my badges very often anyway...

[I was awarded the taxonomist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=1083663) for the tag [default-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-method) which I did not create, not even accidentally as it already happened in [another case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258155/i-got-the-taxonomist-badge-for-a-tag-i-didnt-create).

All I know is that I am the first user who posted a question using that tag, but the tag itself was edited into the question by another user, who is also the one who created the tag along with the first version of the wiki.
This user never received a taxonomist badge AFAICT.

As I said, this happened already a while ago, so it is possible that the behavior already changed by now, but shouldn't my badge go to someone else?

Comment: "but the tag itself was edited into the question by another user" This is not what the [revs history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19976487/revisions) says. According to this page, the one edit that occurred on that post was to add the [interface] tag, but the [default-method] one was there from the first rev.

Comment: Badges? SO has badges? We can be awarded badges? Why was I not informed of this? I need to re-evaluate how I gamify...

Comment: @Tanner I think you're doing just fine if you got to 17k reputation without ever checking your activity page. If you did check it, I think it's your need for vision correction you should reevaluate ;)

Comment: @Aaron I think I need to re-evaluate how subtle my sarcasm is... perhaps I should have added _italics_ or I should create a feature request to introduce a [sarcasm font](https://thenextweb.com/dd/2011/12/12/finally-sarcasm-has-a-voice-in-print-with-its-own-font/) for commenting on meta :-)

Comment: I was gonna go with... [_Badges... you want Badges..._](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4h9xcdtyrE&feature=youtu.be&t=59) but that would have been a little more obscure...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You did create it, look at top right corner of the page, it says "created  7 years, 1 month ago by GOTO 0":

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/default-method/info

You created it because you were the first one posting on it, and created it out of nothing, the first question of the [default-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/default-method) tag was:

[Explicitly calling a default method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976487/explicitly-calling-a-default-method-in-java)

Which was posted by you.

So there is no question, you **did** create the tag.

Comment: But I didn't create "jemalloc" tag. I've never ever used in any of my questions or Edit-Tags of others' questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jemalloc/info shows me on top.
But history (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37735560/revisions) shows Sean (https://stackoverflow.com/users/26095/sean) who created this.

Comment: For almost all tags, the creator is wrongly shown/awarded. See, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-json for example. For many taxonomist badges awarded, the tag itself doesn't exist! (Found from: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist)

Comment: @Ajay It is not the tag wiki that shows who created it, it is who edited in or who posted with this tag, the first questions revisions shows that you putted the tag in: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37732361/2

Comment: Fair enough! Though it's confusing!